# To fix this error, please set your vbnn in the application settings editor

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

i got the below error:
To fix this error, please set your vbnn in the application settings editor. Once it has been set, users will be redirected to that URL instead of this page after logging in

i use the CSASPNETFacebookApp sample i just change appID and appSecret and other web.config settings then upload to ftp. i change my application settings according to getting started page

but when i call my facebook application page i got that error. what is that mean? what is vbnn ? and how can i solve it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking thru the latest version of the code and cannot find any reference to this error message, including specifically the "vbnn" part. It's possible your files are out of sync between the server and your local code.